# is it possible to have two non-isomorphic non-regular graphs with the same adjacent spectrum and the same laplacian spectrum?

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory, laplacian, adjacency-matrices

For two regular graphs $G$ and $H$, it is possible for them to share the same adjacent spectrum and the same laplacian spectrum. While, on the other hand, is it possible to have two non-regular graphs $G$ and $H$, which share the same adjacent spectrum and the same laplacian spectrum? Any comments or references would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, Brendan McKay showed that almost all trees have mates that are simultaneously cospectral in both adjacency and Laplacian spectra. And more.

http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/SpectralTrees.pdf

Edit: I wondered briefly what the smallest pair of such trees would be, and a few minutes of Sage told me that there are two on 11 vertices.

And here they are (for some reason I am having difficulty with the image uploader):

[image]

[image]